# AWS Lambda function error: Cannot find module 'lambda'

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to deploy a REST API in AWS using serverless. Node version 14.17.5.

My directory structure:

[image]

When I deploy the above successfully I get the following error while trying to access the api.

```
2021-09-28T18:32:27.576Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Must use import to load ES Module: /var/task/lambda.js\nrequire() of ES modules is not supported.\nrequire() of /var/task/lambda.js from /var/runtime/UserFunction.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains \"type\": \"module\" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.\nInstead rename lambda.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove \"type\": \"module\" from /var/task/package.json.\n",
    "code": "ERR_REQUIRE_ESM",
    "stack": [
        "Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /var/task/lambda.js",
        "require() of ES modules is not supported.",
        "require() of /var/task/lambda.js from /var/runtime/UserFunction.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains \"type\": \"module\" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.",
        "Instead rename lambda.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove \"type\": \"module\" from /var/task/package.json.",
        "",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:13)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)",
        "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)",
        "    at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)"
    ]
}
```

As per the suggestion in the error I tried changing the lambda.js to lambda.cjs. Now I get the following error

```
 2021-09-28T17:32:36.970Z   undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'lambda'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
"stack": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'lambda'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
}
```

serverless.yml

```
service: APINAME   #Name of your App
useDotenv: true
configValidationMode: error

provider:
 name: aws
 runtime: nodejs14.x # Node JS version
 memorySize: 512
 timeout: 15
 stage: dev
 region: us-east-1 # AWS region
 lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

functions:
 api:
   handler: lambda.handler
   events:
     - http: ANY /{proxy+}
     - http: ANY /
```

lambda.js

```
import awsServerlessExpress from 'aws-serverless-express'
import app from './index.js'

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)
export const handler = (event, context) => {
    awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context)
}
```

aws-cli commands

```
 docker run --rm -it amazon/aws-cli --version
 docker run --rm -it amazon/aws-cli configure
 docker run --rm -it amazon/aws-cli serverless deploy
```

serverless commands:

```
 docker run --rm -it amazon/aws-cli serverless deploy
 serverless config credentials --provider aws --key <KEY> --secret <SECRET>
 node ./node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless config credentials --provider aws --key <KEY> --secret <SECRET>
```

After reading up a couple of answers I have tried the following:

1. Made sure package.json includes "type": "module"
2. Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalled all of them (since the version of node was updated during development)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are you deploying them? Through cdk or the cli or a cloudformation template? That is likely where the culprit is - the api gateway is not properly getting the lambda's arn to be able to connect to it

Comment: I am using aws-cli. I roughly followed this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_mv0ACpamo&t=1113s. But I used docker as in docker run --rm -it amazon/aws-cli ...

Comment: can you update your post with what the cli command you are using is? Pretty sure thats the issue - wherever you are telling the SDK to find the lambda file it can't find it.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with all the necessary details. Please let me know if anymore details are required.

Comment: hmm - The commands seem right, so I think it may be the serverless template now - but I'm not confident enough in my knowledge of that template structure to be certain. In a cloudformation version using the serverless transform, you have a property called CodeUri that will give the base directory for where your lambda file is located - in your case it would just be `CodeUri: ./` -- does the straight up SAM template have a similar property?

Comment: Have been scrolling up and down this page for a while looking for the same https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml. May be I missed something.

Comment: Okay, I *think* it has to do with this property section:  `package: patterns: # Specify the directories and files which should be included in the deployment package for this specific function.` -- if I am guessing correctly based on my knowledge of cloudformation and CDK that if you define the lambda.js path in here it will bundle it when deployed into the artifact that creates the lambda.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried package: patterns: - ./lambda.js | lambda.js | ./lambda.cjs | lambda.cjs with individually true and false for each case. The errors are the same.

Comment: I think this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808998/cannot-use-es6-on-aws-lambda-function-how-to-import-es6-module-within-lambda/68817694#68817694) regards a very similar problem at the core. Maybe you can look at my answer there. It might help you out.

Comment: I read your answer. Regarding 'I have tested the "type": "module" in AWS Lambda, and this seems to work.' - Did you use a .js file at the entry point? If so could you please have a look at the code for lambda.js and let me know if there is a problem there? Or anywhere else for that matter? I am confused about why does say "require()  of ES modules is not supported" when there is no require in the code.

Comment: @Saptarshi Do you have a require in one of the dependencies that you're importing? Because, like I said, I have not tested the interoperability between the require and the import when using the `type: module` solution. But the index.js file will need to use the `import` as well.

Comment: Yes. Many node modules do have require in them. Which is why changing everything made more sense. I have posted my answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converted all imports to `require()` and all exports to `module.exports`

Removed `"type": "module"` from `package.json`

Everything works like a charm. It is not a solution to the question asked but making things work became more important.

Answer (score 1):

Instead rename lambda.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use

`import(),`

and remove

`"type": "module"`

from `/var/task/package.json`. It is there in the error.

Comment: Tried and failed! But thanks!

Comment: I am having trouble reading this. Are you quoting another person (hence the quotes) or writing an answer?

Comment: @mikemaccana , I meant it was in the error, edited it to make it clear

Comment: @Jandroid Thanks! That makes it clearer, I've made some further edits just to fix the markdown.

Comment: In theory this seems like it should work, but it doesn't.