# AWS Lambda Node 18.x ESM Module simple import of .js file

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, es6-modules

I got following error in as ESM Project on AWS Lambda Node 18.x:

```
{ 
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/src/storefront/api/checkout/preview' imported from /var/task/src/storefront/api/checkout/index.js",
  "code": "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
...
}
```

The error refers to this simple barelling in **index.js**:

```
export { preview } from './preview';
...
```

Adding **.js** to the export fixes the error:

```
export { preview } from './preview.js';
```

So not a path reference or permission problem. But that knowledge doesn't help me much because my code is automatically compiled from typescript to esm javascript and I would think that import without .js is standard.
Anyone an idea why lambda makes this problems and how to fix it?

Here my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "checkout",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  },
 ...
```

**tsconfig.js**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "outDir": ".build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es2022"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
    "exclude": [   
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I deployed with **serverless.yml** (`runtime: nodejs18.x`) and **serverless-typescript** plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks similar to this question:

[Cannot use ES6 on AWS Lambda function; how to import ES6 module within Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808998/cannot-use-es6-on-aws-lambda-function-how-to-import-es6-module-within-lambda)

TLDR:

AWS Lambda needs the handler to be configured in the form of filename.methodname, it will always use the .js extension, which makes it not possible to use a different file extension for your entry point.

Comment: Thats it, didn't find that, because i was searching for esm.
Pretty heated discussion with community and typescript team.
ESM imports require file extension which is fine. Typescript team refuses to add the file extension automatically when compiling and suggest to add the file extension in the typescript code. Insane thing is that you should use `.js` extension instead of `.ts`. It looks like you are importing javascript in a ts file. I am getting so tired of sorting out these eco system problems. Seriously considering to switch to elixir or similar where the basics come out of the box.

Comment: That is true. For serverless applications, this is a big pain point - I myself didn't understand it completely even after being three months in a project and I instead decided to move on to other NodeJS projects.

Currently I'm trying out NestJS. Anyway, if the provided answer was a solution to your issue then mark the answer as an accepted one so that others will find it as a reference in future.